# Windows Task Scheduler - On Idle Trigger Not Always Working

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

**Scenario**

I'm using Windows Task Scheduler to accomplish the following:

- run program when system is idle
- stop program when system is no longer idle (user moves mouse etc)
- re-run the program when system enters idle again
- rinse and repeat indefinitely

**Problem**

This works after computer restart and thereafter for some time but at some point it stops working and I am having a difficult time figuring out why.

**Question**

How can I figured out why this task eventually fails and/or how do I fix it ?

***Current task settings***

General

- Use user account: My Computer/Jackson
- Run whether user is logged on or not: Checked

Triggers

- On idle: When computer is idle: Enabled

Actions

- Start a program: C:/Users/Jackson/xyz.exe

Conditions

- Start the task only if computer is idle for: 1 minute
- Wait for idle for: 1 minute
- Stop if the computer ceased to be idle: Checked
- Restart if the idle state resumes: Checked
- Wake the computer to run this task: Checked
- Start only if the following network connection is available: Any connection

Settings

- Allow task to be run on demand: Checked
- Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed: Checked
- If the task fails, restart every: 1 minute
- Attempt to restart up to: 3 times
- If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop: Checked
- If the task is already running, then the following rule applies: Do not start a new instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this question I had a thought to change **Settings:Attempt Restart** from `3` to `999`. This ***seems*** to be working so far.

The theory is that after 3 iterations of idling then returning to normal use this schedule won't restart anymore until windows is restarted also resetting the "restart counter" back to 0.

***Strong Note***

"idle" seems to correspond with screen saver. So when you screen saver is active then your computer is rendered as "idle". This seems as intuitive as not-intuitive. Anyway, make sure you have a screen saver setup if you want to use an idle schedule.

## ** EDIT **

Now days I am not checking "wait for idle" at all. The idea being that I don't want to wait for idle to check for idle, since the trigger is "idle" the trigger should trip once the system is considered idle. I also use "on workstation lock" and have the screensaver set to "show password on resume" so I'm not sure which route is actually being used. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info, but if you stopped using "wait for idle", what setting do you use instead? I'm trying to do the same thing and having the same issue.